# Bad Request on JsvServiceClient.get but not JsvServiceClient.send

Tags: c#, servicestack

Running ServiceStack 4.0.44 I have the following  on my test client:

```
return client.Send(new GetVendor { VenCode = vencode });
```

vs what I had

```
// return client.Get(new GetVendor { VenCode = vencode });
```

and then on the server I have/had

```
public class VendorsService : Service {

    public object Any(GetVendor request) {
        var vendor = Db.SingleWhere<Vendors>("VenCode", request.VenCode);
        return vendor;
    }
    //public object Get(GetVendor request) {
    //    var vendor = Db.SingleWhere<Vendors>("VenCode", request.VenCode);
    //    return vendor;
    //}

}

//[Route("/vendor/{VenCode}", "GET")]
[Route("/vendor/{VenCode}")]
public class GetVendor : IReturn<Vendors> {
    public string VenCode { get; set; }
}
public class Vendors {
    :
    :
}
```

My question is why when I pass "B&T" for VenCode -- and I understand that IIS is interpreting the & as part of the URL -- why does the Send work and return Vendors -- but the Get blows up with Bad Request unless I put

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
```

into my web.config

Bottom line what is the difference? How would I implement CRUD routines with all the html special characters without modifying the registry etc?  Or do I need to urlEncode them somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `Get()` API sends the request using the `?QueryString` which is what **requestPathInvalidCharacters** is validating against.

When you use `Send()` you're sending a JSV serialized Request DTO via a HTTP POST which isn't validated by requestPathInvalidCharacters.

It's unlikely there's any way to disable ASP.NET's default behavior other than using Web.config, note this validation happens in ASP.NET before the request reaches ServiceStack.

Comment: Thanks so much -- very helpful